# Find and replace word vba vb.net

Tags: vb.net, vba

I have a small problem with my find and replace.
It will not find and replace my text in the Header.

Im using VB.net to open a word document to search and replace

Does anyone know why?

```
With wdRng.Find
            oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="ELEKUND", ReplaceWith:=kund, Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
            While oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
                oDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="  ", ReplaceWith:=" ", Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue)
            End While
        End With
```

Comment: _why_? - because `wdRng` does not point to the header range.  Take some time to learn about the Word Object Model. [Understanding the Word Object Model from a .NET Developer's Perspective](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192495(v=office.11).aspx).  Pay attention to the section on the [The Document Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa192495(v=office.11).aspx#wordobject_link6).

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment @TnTinMn